# Selecting the first option from the select tag using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a select tag such as this:

```
<select name="select_tag">
<option value="">...</option>
<option value="Val1">Value1</option>
<option value="Val2">Value2</option>
<option value="Val3">Value3</option>
<option value="Val4">Value4</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to parse the above from a web page using beautiful script and select an option and send that payload. I'm using the following code:

```
sauce = . . . . 
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")
payload = dict()
inputs = form.findAll('select')
for i in inputs:
    input_1 = i.get('name')
    option_value = soup.find('option').get('value')
    payload[input_1] = option_value
    print(payload)
```

My Objective : Find the select tag in a form, find its name, **get the VALUE FROM ANY OPTION TAG WHOSE VALUE IS NOT EMPTY** (Anyone value from the available option tags where there is some value), send the payload.

However when I run the above script I get the option_value as 'none'.
For example = Value of Payload Dict: Payload = {'select_tag':'none'}

Would be appreciable if someone could also specify an answer for  element just like the  element

Answer (score 0):

You are using find for option instead you should use findAll to find all the options.

```
sauce = . . . . 
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")
payload = dict()
inputs = soup.findAll('select')
for i in inputs:
    input_1 = i.get('name')
    for opt in i.findAll('option'):
        option_value = opt.get('value')
        payload[input_1] = option_value
    print(payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting this line

```
option_value = soup.find('option').get('value')
```

to do something different every time your code calls it. But it doesn't. It identifies the first `<option>` tag each time and that one has the blank attribute `value` that you don't want.

Try this:

```
option_tags=soup.findAll('option')
values = [v.get('value') for v in option_tags]
# Now you have ['', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val4'], remove the blank
values = list(filter(None,values))
# Now you have ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val4']
```

I'm not clear on what the loop is supposed to do so I can't tell you what to do with `values` once you have it.

Comment: My code is kind of cumbersome. What I want is to send one single payload of the any value from the any option value. For example if there are 3 options (Drop-downs) Orange, Apple, Grapes. My payload should be {'select-tag':'Orange'} (Or any fruit, but the value should not be empty, thats it)